# Where do I write (common) functions that will be called by more than one model (cakephp)?

Tags: php, cakephp, before-save, cakephp-model

Suppose I have **Model1** and **Model2**. Inside each **beforeSave()** I want to call function **f()**.

1. Where do I have to put **f()**?
2. How can I call it inside the Model's **beforeSave()** function (syntax problem)?

PS: I wanna do something like changing the name of the file uploaded before saving it in the Database. I know how to do the upload but not where to put that method so I can use it in another models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice Question,

You can use AppModel.php

```
<?php
  class AppModel extends Model{

    function f1($arg){
           // some code     
    }
  }
?>
```

From model1 and model2 you can call it as given below:

```
<?php
  class Model1 extends AppModel{

    function beforeSave(){
         $this->f1($arg1);
           // some code     
    }
  }
?>
```

I think this will solve above problem!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank, you. This already solved my problem but just out of curiosity, if I want to use f1() for many models and inside many controllers (something useful like a strtolower function), Do I have to make any changes?

Comment: You can use f1() in all models as Model class extends App model, But in case of controller you have to create same function in AppController, Because from controller you cannot access function of Model directly, You have to make object of that class....

Answer (score 3):

A `Behavior` has events that you can hook into - one of them being `beforeSave()` callback.

Make a behavior and attach it to the models that need that behavior.

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html for more info.